# SQL Sending email with values derived from table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email

Consider this following html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stuff here</title>
    </head>
        <p>
           Value: @@ Table.column @ 
       </p>
 </html>
```

This HTML is a value in a table. 
The email is then spawned and sent. 
My question is how does SQL send this email, and more specifically how is the value from "@@ Table.column@ " inserted into the email?

Is this done through stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. Look here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(Body VARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('This is the body of email bla bla ......')
```

### Query

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

SET @tableHTML =
    N'<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stuff here</title>
    </head>
    ' +

    CAST ( ( SELECT Body
                FROM @TABLE    
              FOR XML PATH('p'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</html>' ;
SELECT @tableHTML;   --<-- use this variable to pass value to your sp_send_dbmail 
                        -- @body parameter
```

### Result

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stuff here</title>
    </head>
    <p><Body>This is the body of email bla bla ......</Body></p></html>
```